# Ruby: How to find superclass of an object?

Tags: ruby

In ruby I can find the class of an object by calling the 'class' method:

```
5.class
'foo'.class
3.14.class
```

How do I find the superclass?

Comment: You can also call .class.class

Comment: @Dbz no, that will always be `Class`

Comment: What does this tell you? `ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |c| c.superclass.nil? } #=> [BasicObject]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work

```
5.class
=> Fixnum
5.class.superclass
=> Integer
```

You can also use [ancestors](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-ancestors) method which will give you a list of all the superclasses

```
 5.class.ancestors
 =>  [Fixnum, Integer, Numeric, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Comment: thanks guys, that was quick. I like this one best because it also gave me the ancestors method, which I didn't know existed. I'm returning to ruby after a long time.

Comment: `Module#ancestors` will also give you mixins, but not singleton classes, which are technically also ancestors (in some sense, i.e. they are also searched during method lookup).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.superclass` like:

```
3.14.class.superclass
```

More info about that mhetod  you can [find here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-i-superclass).

Answer (score 2):

You call the `superclass` method on the `class`

```
2.1.2 :003 > 5.class.superclass
 => Integer
```

#### Reference

[Class#superclass](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-i-superclass)